# Laravel trouble routing to update Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to edit a Alumne model with a model Form but I only have a NotFoundHttpException

The application only fails when I confirm the edit form. I think the problem is in the Form::model line but don't know.

Here's the entire code:

http://laravel.io/bin/62eq

Thanks.

Comment: Post your code here, don't just link to it. Also, try to clarify your question, it's really hard to understand as it is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All looks correct...

Check if `$alumne` really has `id` or is named different like `alumne_id` or `id_alumne`... Is the only thing may be.

Comment: Thanks! it was `id_alumne`...Such a big noob mistake